# Horizontal scrolling site

Tags: safari, horizontal-scrolling

I have a horizontal scrolling site that uses jquery to reverse the mouse axis on the scroll wheel on the mouse. This works fine on every browser apart from safari. The address of the page with the scrolling is here: http://www.jamesbells.com/index.php?page=alias

Can anyone help - all I need is for the mouse wheel to scroll left and right when moved up and down.

Cheers

Jon

Comment: Please phrase your question in a concise way that does not require visiting external sites to actually see the problem. Try to refine the problem to a short sample.

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://flowplayer.org/tools/scrollable/) could be another way to go with more customizations available.